# only one scroll bar working

Tags: css, horizontal-scrolling

I have a table that has a fixed height and width.
I have mentioned height as 200px and width as 100%(inside another div of 600Px width)
now I am adding a new column at run time so the width needs to be increased so I thought to put a scroll bar. 
I am doing the following to achieve this

```
$('.showDateTime').show();
$('.showDateTime').css("width", "300px");
$('#TransactionErrorsTableData').css("overflow-x", "scroll");
```

The issue is that the horizontal scroll bar comes but is disabled.
Where as the vertical scroll bar is working fine. 
I have set overflow as auto for my div "TransactionErrorsTableData"

Any idea on how to enable the horizontal scroll bar?

P.S. I m kind of stuck up so please pardon if the question is not clear, please comment if any details are required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I cannot accurately get your exact problem seeing you only posted a snippet, and didn't post any examples, but I'll give it a go.

If you use the CSS rules `overflow-x: scroll` or `overflow-y: scroll`, it forces most browsers to make the scroll-bars appear, this is by design, so that if the content enlarges, the content outside of the container will not be forced to move around.

The scroll-bar is **not** disabled, it is just inactive due to it not having enough content to actually be able to scroll, I am guessing this is because you have set `.showDateTime`'s width to a specific amount, which is inside of the `TransactionErrorsTableData` div.

I hope this helps!

**NOTE :**

This answer all assumed due to not enough details given.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I have also tried doing the overflow-y: scroll thing, and it indeed happen to show the disabled/inactive scroll bar, and my content had to shift to next row to adjust itself..

Comment: Maybe try adding your code into jsfiddle.net so I can see what you've done and debug it from there

Answer (score 0):

Try it, but would be better an jsfiddler:

```
$('#TransactionErrorsTableData').css("overflow-x", "auto");
```